# Trouble with "show" and "index" routes in model with many to one relationship Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes, relationship

I feel like the solution to this is actually quite simple but I can't figure it out.

https://github.com/kingdavidek/StuddyBuddy

I am writing an app to help me summarize non fiction books. I want to have a view for the book(or Piece) and then a one to many relationship with chapters/sections, where each section has its own view. I also want the ability to make subsections with many to one relationship to sections etc.

So this will be a kind of tree like structure where each smaller section will have its own summary. (I am basically following the jumpstart lab blogger project but adapting it for my own use. http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#blogger-2 )

I have been able to create the view for the piece successfully and links to the sections. I got to the part with the comments on the jumpstart tutorial, where Comments have a many to one relationship with Articles, and where comments are displayed under the parent article. I wanted to use the same concept for sections/chapters, except that I would like to link to each individual section and display by itself in a new view.

the routes for the section model say:

```
        piece_section GET    /pieces/:piece_id/sections/:id(.:format)      sections#show
        piece_sections GET    /pieces/:piece_id/sections(.:format)          sections#index
```

I am having trouble displaying an individual section in a new page.

My first problem is that I cannot link directly to the show action of an individual section, and I don't know why:

Here is the relevant part in show.html.erb for the parent "Piece" or book:

```
<% @pieces.sections.each do |section| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to section.name, piece_section_path(section), class: 'section_name' %>
      <!-- this middle part 'piece.name' is the psart we want the link to say, the next part is our route helper.-->
    </li>
  <% end %>
<%= link_to "delete", piece_path(@pieces), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete the article?"}
```

%>

the parent "Piece" controller:

```
def show
    @pieces = Piece.find(params[:id])
end
```

When i try to do this I get the following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Pieces#show
 Showing /home/david/Documents/Learning/StuddyBuddy/app/views/pieces/show.html.erb where line #9 raised:
 No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"sections", :id=>nil, :piece_id=>#<Section id: 1, name: "xama", broader_context: "hahahah", summary: nil, key_questions_addressed: nil, thoughts: nil, piece_id: 1, created_at: "2016-07-28 10:46:05", updated_at: "2016-07-28 10:46:05">} missing required keys: [:id]
<%= link_to section.name, piece_section_path(section), class: 'section_name' %>
```

When I link to the index action of the sections model it works however, and I see the "show" action of the parent "Piece" perfectly fine.

My SECOND problem is when I am on the view for the Piece. I try to click on an individual section (ie. this link:

```
<%= link_to section.name, piece_sections_path(section), class: 'section_name' %>
```

)

And for some reason I cannot display the section and the columns of the Section model.

Here is the section controller:

```
class SectionsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @pieces = Piece.find(params[:piece_id])
    @sections = @pieces.sections.find(params[:section_id])
end

def show
    @sections = Section.all
    #@sections = Piece.sections.find(params[:id])
    #@sections = @piece.sections.all
    #@sections.piece_id = @pieces.id
end
end
```

Here is the index.html.erb file for the Section model:

```
<h1> Yoyo</h1>
<p>Piece: <%= @pieces.name%></p>
<p> Section: <%= @sections.name%></p>
<p> Broader Context: <%= @sections.broader_context %></p>
```

Here is the routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

      root to: 'articles#index'

      resources :pieces do
        resources :sections
      end
end
```

The problem i get is this:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SectionsController#index
Couldn't find Section without an ID

Request
Parameters:
{"piece_id"=>"1"}
```

What I don't understand here is how I do not have access to the section id?? How is it I only have access to the piece_id??

I would really appreciate the help as I have been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass piece id to link to helper as `piece_section_path` need two params

```
piece_section GET    /pieces/:piece_id/sections/:id(.:format)      sections#show
```

- `:piece_id`
- `:id` (`section_id`)

Change your link to:

```
<%= link_to section.name, piece_section_path(@pieces, section), class: 'section_name' %>
```

Comment: Thank you this was the problem! I appreciate you taking the time to read and answer me!